# Do you need homes for NPCs spawned with Spawners?

Tags: starbound

I was reading on [Both](http://starbound.wikia.com/wiki/Human_Spawner) [Wikis](http://starbound.gamepedia.com/Human_Spawner) that you can spawn humans and guards, i am wondering if you need homes for them

Comment: I was just wondering what you would even use those spawners for anyways.

Comment: @Katustrawfic personally, to start building the Holy Empire of Li Britannia. The Wikia Wiki says they can also plant seeds so they can set up some basic farming for you plus Guard Spawners can spawn guards, useful for defenses

Comment: Can you set-up your own little town with merchants as well?

Comment: @Katustrawfic it's not documented in either wiki if NPCs spawned can become merchants or not, it only says about crops and fighting enemies for guards but it's an idea the developers can use

Comment: There are spawners specifically for merchants. IIRC you can craft a stim merchant spawner, and you can find others as rare drops or in chests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you do not. However, an NPC without a shelter will most likely be quickly killed by the native wildlife, so I would recommend giving them some sort of protection.

Comment: what i just found out is, you can spawn them in your ship. just be carfull not to shoot them :-D